# Sorting columns on celltable

Tags: java, gwt

i have some missunderstanding with sorting of celltable columns, if i click of column header by first selected item it sorts this column, but when i click to another item and then click to sort this columns property it will be shown in the column the last item properties and new one is not seen.

```
void update() {

    final ListDataProvider<M> listProvider=new ListDataProvider<M> ();
    listProvider.addDataDisplay(m);
    final List<M> list=listProvider.getList();

    sort=new ListHandler<M>(list);
    m.addColumnSortHandler(sort);
    listProvider.refresh();

    AsyncCallback<List<M>> callback = new AsyncCallback<List<M>>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final List<M> result) {

            for (final M m : result) {

            list.add(m);

            }

        }   
    };

    rpcService.getData(dID, callback);
```

what can cause this problem, any suggestions?

Comment: Slightly offtopic (but maybe it could straighten this whole situation) - shouldn't you be using `AsyncDataProvider` instead of ListDataProvider when loading data from an async service? There's `AsyncHandler` that goes with it too, for sorting :) Just mentioning this, in case you missed it.